# How to execute a task on another host without changing the deploy host [Deployer]?

Tags: php, hosts, php-deployer

I want to write a script that connects to a 2nd host to execute commands there.

with `dep deploy stage` it should executes task on **host: live** too

1. It connects to host: live

   makes a db-dump

   and downloads is to the deploy-computer
2. It connects to host: stage

   uploads the db-dump

   and integrates it there

The basic parts of mysql-dump end mysl-import I know, but how to execute a task on another host?

Thanks for pointing to the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside each task you can run the "on" function. For this you can supply a host (in your example during a "live" task you would supply "stage"):

```
        on(host('stage'), function () {
            // do something
        });
```

If you need to supply some variables (e.g. dynamically created filenames) you can hand them to the new function like with `use`. So if your task saved your dump to the filename $mysqlDumpFilename, e.g.:

```
        on(host('stage'), function () use ($mysqlDumpFilename) {
            // do something
        });
```

Docs: https://deployer.org/docs/api#on

Comment: this way it works, but for what is the **use ($mysqlDumpFilename)** part?

Comment: To hand over a variable/value from the current task to the new on task. You can remove it completely, if you don't need to hand over variables.